# cakephp matching inputed data to textbox from database fields

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am new to cakephp and I am currently working on this app where I need (for security purposes) to match data of inputted student ID on the data from my studentlist table. So in my studentlist table I have two fields one is the id and the other is the studentid so whenever a student wants to register to the website he/she needs to enter a studentid and when the studentid that is entered is not on the database he/she cannot register.

I have this view/add code

```
echo $this->Form->input('studentlist_id', array('type'=>'text', 'label'=>'Student ID'));
```

and my model code

```
var $name = 'Studentlist';
var $displayField = 'studentid';
var $validate = array(
    'id' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
```

and my users_controller code

```
$studentlists = $this->User->Studentlist->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('studentlists'));
```

please help... I've been searching and tweaking the codes but can't seem to find the answers... I am like really new to cakephp so I am really sorry in advance...

Answer (score 1):

this may help you,

```
$count = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions'=>array('User.studentid'=>$_POST['studentlist_id']))); 
if($count > 0){
echo "Student Exist";
}else {
***do something***
}
```